# wlan off when turning on computer

Tags: 18.04, wireless

sometimes when I turn on my laptop its on flight mode, when I turn off flight mode Bluetooth is turned on. 
`ifconfig` says device not found, i.e I cant connect to the internet. if I restart the computer it solves the problem. I am very curious about why this is happening and especially why it only happens approximately 1 out of 10 times. How can I find out?

Thanks!